# Concerning Wilsons Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question in Elementary Number Theory.

In Elementary number theory(6th) page 96 exercise 5, written by David M. Burton, I can prove (a), i.e., "An integer $n >1$ is prime if and only if n divides $(n-2)!-1$" by using Wilsons Theorem. But, I don't know how to prove (b).

The problem (b) is :
If $n$ is a composite integer, show that n divides $(n-1)!$, except when n=4.

I think that this can be proved by using (a), but I don't know how to do it.
If you give me some hints, I'll appreciate it ! :)

Comment: If $n$ is a composite integer, let $p$ its smallest prime divisor. Then both, $p$ and $\frac{n}{p}$ are factors of $(n-1)!$. They are distinct unless - what? And if the two are not distinct, what makes $4$ so special?

Comment: As a rule, better to just lead with the question. The previous question doesn't really add much information, and it makes people read a lot of irrelevant stuff to get to your question.

Answer (score 4):

1) If $n\not =p^2$ where $p$ is a prime number, taking a prime factor $P$ of $n$, $(n-1)!$ has two distinct number $P, n/P$, so $n(=P\times n/P)$ divides $(n-1)!$.

2) If $n=p^2\gt 4$, since $p\ge 3$, $(n-1)!$ has two distinct number $p, 2p$. Hence, $n=p^2$ divides $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 0):

From Wilson's Theorem we have:

$$(p-1)!+1 - p(p-2)! \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$-(p-2)!(p - (p-1)) + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$-(p-2)! + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

$$(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Hence the proof.

Comment: he knows how to prove (a)